# Getting username from GuildMember

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I was coding a guildMemberAdd and a guildMemberRemove I ran across an issue... So, I was wondering, how do you obtain the user's username and discriminator from when they join? as when I tried `member.username` and `member.discriminator` it logs as `undefined` and `undefined`
Code below, nothing was printed to console upon this issue:

```
exports.run = (client, member) => {
  member.guild.channels.find(`name`, `mod-logs`).send({embed: {
    "color": 8311585,
    "footer": {
      "text": "Bot made by: Pawxeric#0858"
    },
    "author": {
      "name": "New Member",
      "icon_url": member.avatarURL
    },
    "fields": [
      {"name": `${member.username}#${member.discriminator}`, // logs as undefined#undefined
      "value": "Joined"}
    ]
  }});
}
```

Also, the code is having issues picking up anything that uses the `member` value. Like `avatarURL`, `username`, and `discriminator`. If there's something I'm missing, please share down below :3c

Comment: Are you sure that `member.guild.channels.find(\`name\`, \`mod-logs\`)` is returning something?  Also, you don't need backticks " ` " here because you aren't utilizing variables.  You might as well use double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to get properties from a user object

```
<member>.user
```

User has username, discriminator and avatarurl.

The full object can be found on https://discord.js.org/

Comment: Someone actually told me this after you answered it, but I wasn't paying attention to Stack Overflow, but thanks anyways :)

Comment: Np, glad I could semi-help! :)